# How do I get a web scraper to return desired outputs?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

What am I overlooking here? Trying to learn and get this code to pull back name, price, and pull back the large image link (that is found on the product detail page when you click on the product image) as a learning exercise.

Issue

1. My loop is not pulling back all products as I would expect only the first of each page
2. I can not get to the largest image (that is found when you go to the product page, click on the image)

If you can help me correct my code it will be very much appreciated

John

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# from urllib import urlretrieve

for pgnum in range(1, 4):
    url = f"https://www.marksandspencer.com/l/wine-shop/wine-beer-and-spirits/vegan-wine?page={pgnum}"
    response = requests.get(url)
    website_html = response.text
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(website_html, "html.parser")
    search_results = soup.find_all('ul', class_="grid grid-4")
    
    for search_result in search_results:
        name = search_result.find('h3', class_="product__title").text

        try:
            price = search_result.find("div", class_="product__price").text
        except:
            price = 'No Price'

        print(f'''Wine Name: {name}''')
        print(f'''Wine Price: {price.replace('Current Price','')}''')

        link = search_result.find("a", class_="product product__atb")
        ProductPageLink = "https://www.marksandspencer.com" + link['href']
        print(f'''Detailed Product Page Link: {ProductPageLink}''')

        # get the full resolution product image
        response = requests.get(ProductPageLink)
        time.sleep(1)  # rate limit
        wine_page_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
        images = wine_page_soup.find('img', class_='full-width', srcset=True)
        print(f'''Large Image: {images['src'].strip()}''')

        image_URL="https://www.marksandspencer.com" + images['src'].strip()
        print(f'''Image URL: {images['src'].strip()}\n''')
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice, you are processing the `li` inside `ul`, so instead, you should trying to get a list of `li` element, but not simple `ul`.

```py
import time
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# from urllib import urlretrieve

for pgnum in range(1, 4):
    print('processing page: ' + str(pgnum))
    url = f"https://www.marksandspencer.com/l/wine-shop/wine-beer-and-spirits/vegan-wine?page={pgnum}"
    response = requests.get(url)
    website_html = response.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(website_html, "html.parser")
    search_results = soup.find_all('li', class_=re.compile("grid__tile grid__tile"))

    for search_result in search_results:
        name = search_result.find('h3', class_="product__title").text

        try:
            price = search_result.find("div", class_="product__price").text
        except:
            price = 'No Price'

        print(f'''Wine Name: {name}''')
        print(f'''Wine Price: {price.replace('Current Price','')}''')

        link = search_result.find("a", class_="product product__atb")
        ProductPageLink = "https://www.marksandspencer.com" + link['href']
        print(f'''Detailed Product Page Link: {ProductPageLink}''')

        # get the full resolution product image
        response = requests.get(ProductPageLink)
        time.sleep(1)  # rate limit
        wine_page_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
        images = wine_page_soup.find('img', class_='full-width', srcset=True)
        print(f'''Large Image: {images['src'].strip()}''')

        image_URL="https://www.marksandspencer.com" + images['src'].strip()
        print(f'''Image URL: {images['src'].strip()}\n''')
```

Comment: Hi Prayson, 
Thank you for taking the time to work out what was wrong with my code. I am very grateful. 

I have mis-understood and thought I needed to interrogate the highest class level that encloses all the data I am looking for. 

The regex is also new to me but I can see how it works here. thank you for taking the time to help me. 

John

Comment: Almost there. So the last part has stumped me. I just don't know how to retrieve it.

Comment: @GomesGomes just change the params `wid` and `qlt` in url, for example, `wid=1280` then the image is larger than before.